# Positioning text beside a form (Wordpress) Refur Theme

Tags: css, wordpress, css-position

Hi I am using Contact Form 7, I have reduced the width of the form by 50% so that it only takes half of the container, I want the other half to be filled with text, but I am not 100% sure how to do this in the css code, could someone give me a pointer please?

I have uploaded two images of how it looks, and how I want it to look - well essentially.

[Current.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNIJO.png)

[Effect that I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cSqn.png)

Advice is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Stephen.

Comment: Where can we see the theme?

Comment: You'll need to give us a working example or at a least provide us with some HTML and CSS code.

Comment: @Grork The theme can be viewed at https://wp-themes.com/refur/ although there's no contact page

Comment: Oh, well. 
Btw, you need to set width of form and width of text at 50% and then float left both.
You also need a "clearfix" solution ( clear: both ) after those elements or as class assigned to their container.